# Difference in seconds between timestamps in Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to get the difference (in seconds) between two TIMESTAMP values in Sqlite3?

For instance, I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - my_timestamp FROM my_table;
```

And I always get '0'. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (Note, I have verified that my_timestamp is indeed in the past.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Got it:

```
SELECT (julianday(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - julianday(my_timestamp)) * 86400.0) FROM my_table;
```

`julianday` returns the fractional number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. I then take the difference and multiply by the number of seconds per day.

Comment: Yes it does. Running `select (julianday("2015-01-01T12:00:00") - julianday("2015-01-01T11:00:00")) * 24;` yields one hour as expected, or close enough to it: `0.99999999627471`.

Comment: If you're only getting a difference of dates, make sure the input to `julianday` actually is a timestamp and not just a datestamp.

Answer (score 10):

Another variant to the nearest second

```
CAST(strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as integer) - 
CAST(strftime('%s', my_timestamp) as integer)
```