# Difference between two timestamps in SQLite with high precision

Tags: sqlite

I need to get the difference between two timestamps in SQLite.
While searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708167/difference-in-seconds-between-timestamps-in-sqlite3), and while the accepted answer seems to work at first glance, it looses a lot of precision:

Taking this query

```
select timestamp, EndTimeStamp, ((julianday(EndTimeStamp)-julianday(timestamp)) * 86400.0) as Duration from X
```

I get this result:

```
"2016-04-18 13:44:31.630916"    "2016-04-18 13:44:31.63114" "0.00100582838058472"
"2016-04-18 13:44:31.6315231"   "2016-04-18 13:44:31.6316997"   "0.0"
"2016-04-18 13:44:31.6320359"   "2016-04-18 13:44:31.632202"    "0.0"
"2016-04-18 13:44:31.6326964"   "2016-04-18 13:44:31.6329361"   "0.0"
```

As you can see, the three last results have a calculated difference of Zero, but the timestamps are actually different.

**Is it possible, in SQL, with the DATETIME field type, to calculate a precise difference? I would prefer to not need to fallback to C#.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), the format interpreted by the built-in  date/time functions is:

> *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS*

In otherwords, they parse only the first three digits of the fractional seconds.

You could try to extract the additional digits with `substr()` and add them to the result with the correct scale.

Comment: I just now realised that SQLite saves the date as a string, not as a dedicated DATETIME type, so now the behaviour kind of makes sense. Thank you.